# dbus-send to remote machine

Tags: tcp, dbus

What's the syntax for sending a dbus message to another machines dbus daemon using dbus-send?  I see there's TCP/IP support for the destination address, but I can't find any docs on how to actually specify the address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override the session bus address using the environment variable:

> `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=tcp:host=server.example.org,port=77777 dbus-send ...`

Note that the buses running by default do not listen on TCP. You have to run your own bus instance for that.

Comment: How do you listen on a tcp port on the other end? I guess it gets to be a tcp server and also with a dbus connection...? Thanks in advance for any pointer.

Comment: Ok I see the server side config [is under connecting to dbus over tcp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158684/connecting-to-dbus-over-tcp)